# What are front merges in I/O scheduling and how can I tune this parameter?

Tags: io, scheduling

My Linux uses the **Deadline** algorithm for I/O scheduling. One of the parameters is the `front_merges` parameter under `/sys/block/sda/queue/iosched/front_merges`. By default it is set to 1, which means front merges are likely to occur. One can set it to 0 to gain a performance boost if don't expect front merges to occur.

1. What are front merges exactly? Can someone depict this please?
2. How do I know or test whether front merges occur on my system or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When for example you are reading in a file, you do so from start to end. It's thus beneficial to merge requests to the same or adjacent blocks. This is called back merging, because the newer request is added at the back of the existing one. This is always enabled with the Deadline scheduler.

A lot less common is that you read blocks in reverse order and have a newer request added in front of an existing one.

Both incur overhead to check whether the merge is appropriate. With back merging, it pays off, with front merging it depends more on your workload.

I am not aware of any way to profile this, apart from modifying and recompiling the kernel. Interestingly, till [at least RHEL 5.2](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/pdf/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-5-Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases-en-US.pdf), `front_merges` was turned off by default. In [more recent RHEL versions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/pdf/Performance_Tuning_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-7-Performance_Tuning_Guide-en-US.pdf) it's now on by default. I would just leave it that way.